# Send custom metadata to New Conversation call

Tags: botframework

We are using the Direct Line API to carry conversations between an app and a bot. When we create a new conversation, we would like to include some metadata about the current user. The idea is that the bot would recognize the user and send a personalized message to the user. Is there a way have this behavior happen?

Comment: if it's a new conversation, what user data do you have at that point?

Comment: Some identifiers stored in our our app.